# PCRE libraries version is too old

Tags: php, apache, apache2, centos, pcre

> The Bug Genie 3 requires PCRE librairies 8.0 or later. You have
>   version 7.8 2008-09-05. Update your system to the latest release from
>   your usual sources.

after i look at the problem and try to update my pcre libraries with the following step:

```
wget the latest source of pcre from sourceforge 8.31

# tar -xzf pcre-8.31.tar.gz
# cd pcre-8.31
# ./configure --enable-utf8  --enable-unicode-properties
# make && make install
```

when i do pcretest -C 
i got this

```
[root@server1 /]# pcretest -C
PCRE version 8.31 2012-07-06
Compiled with
  8-bit support only
  UTF-8 support
  Unicode properties support
  No just-in-time compiler support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

and when i do locate, there are a lot

```
[root@server1 /]# locate libpcre
/lib64/libpcre.so.0
/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.a
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.la
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1.0.1
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.a
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.la
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.so
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.a
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.la
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.so
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.so.0.0.1
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpcre.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpcrecpp.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpcreposix.pc
```

finally, i backed to my php info happily.. it still show me version 7.8 installed.

[image]

May i know what should i do to solve this while the open source application buggenie need this . Thx for reply.

Comment: What version of PHP do you have?

Comment: you need find out php load which one, and why not the one you built under /usr/local/lib. maybe LD_LIBRARY_PATH will help, or maybe you need rebuild php or Bug Genie.

Comment: @arsane, may I know which is the right file to declare in php or how to test that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to manually build PHP against newest PCRE library using `--with-pcre-regex=DIR` option. To do so, you need to obtain the PHP sources and PCRE sources, as well as sources of all other libraries you might need.

This page http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php summarizes versions of PCRE bundled with PHP.

The much easier option would be updating PHP using package manager of your OS (perhaps by enabling unstable repositories), but this depends on your OS.

Comment: may i know what is the location of PCRE ? while there're a lot =(

Comment: @SLim It is the location to the directory with PCRE sources (where you have unpacked the `pcre-8.31.tar.gz` archive)

Answer (score 5):

I'm Centos 6.3 user. This worked in my case.

1. Search for existing pcre.

   ```
   rpm -qa | grep pcre
   ```
2. Remove all existing pcre using --nodeps.
3. Download pcre rpm higher than 8.x. 
   I used one from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=pcre
4. Install it using rpm.
5. Restart your web service and check phpinfo. It should reveal the pcre libraries you just installed.

Comment: can you specify exactly which version you installed from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=pcre? I ran into the same problem using CentOS 6.3

Comment: for all others out there running into the same issue: It worked well with ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/sourceforge/f/fu/fuduntu/yum/2012/STABLE/RPMS/pcre-8.10-2.fc14.x86_64.rpm for me.

Answer (score 4):

On Centos 5.9 a modified version of drmanalo's steps worked for us:

1. Search for existing pcre
       rpm -q --queryformat "%{name}.%{arch}\n" pcre
2. Remove all existing pcre using --nodeps
       rpm -ev --nodeps pcre-devel.x86_64
       rpm -ev --nodeps pcre.x86_64
       rpm -ev --nodeps pcre-devel.i386
       rpm -ev --nodeps pcre.i386
3. Added repository
       nano /etc/yum.repos.d/utter-ramblings.repo

> [utter-ramblings]
>   name=Utter Ramblings
>   baseurl=http://www.jasonlitka.com/media/EL5/x86_64/
>   gpgkey=**`#same.url.as.above#`**/media/RPM-GPG-KEY-jlitka
>   enabled=1
>   gpgcheck=1
>
> Installed using yum
>       yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=utter-ramblings install pcre pcre-devel
>
> Restart your web service and check phpinfo

Answer (score 0):

On my Centos 5.9 I could upgrade pcre  from 6.* to 8.* no problem but could not get  it "recognised" by PHP or Apache. Problem solved itself by upgrading php53 to php54