# Rebuild PHP with the newest PCRE

Tags: php, ubuntu, pcre

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server where I updated the PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 but the PCRE version is still at 8.12. I then installed pcre from source and it should be the 8.33 version but php info is still showing 8.12. How can I make PHP use the new version of PCRE?

Comment: Please try with Apache restart

Comment: I did that about a 100 times already...but still v8.12.

Comment: Check the installed version with this command **pcretest -C**.  Please refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212079/pcre-librairies-version-is-too-old

Comment: Did you rebuild PHP with the updated PCRE lib?

Comment: I get: 
pcretest -C
PCRE version 8.33 2013-05-28
...

I installed PHP with apt-get...how can I rebuild? Sorry but I'm still learning..

Comment: The mediawiki installation instructions for Scribuntu (which requires 8.33+) also mention that php reports an older version than `pcretest -C`. It's not clear which version actually gets used though. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Updating_to_PCRE_8.33_or_Higher